# What does ARGS , ARGS_NAMES actually mean in mod_security crs?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-security

What does ARGS , ARGS_NAMES actually mean in mod_security core rule sets?

I have already referred to the [Modsecurity2 Apache Reference](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.1.2/modsecurity2-apache-reference.html#N1061E) but I didnt get any clear idea.

Can someone give me a specific idea , preferably with an explanation, what it actually is and how something actually triggers a rule positive like the one below.

The rule below is triggered positive for cases like " x and 6" etc, in general any "and" followed by a digit. I understand what the request filename is, in this case. what i dont understand is what are ARGS and ARGS_NAMES. I need a specific example with reference to the rule below.

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "(?i)\b(?i:and)\b\s+(\d{1,10}|'[^=]{1,10}')\s*[=]|\b(?i:and)\b\s+(\d{1,10}|'[^=]{1,10}')\s*[<>]|\band\b ?(?:\d{1,10}|[\'\"][^=]{1,10}[\'\"]) ?[=<>]+|\b(?i:and)\b\s+(\d{1,10}|'[^=]{1,10}')" \
    "phase:2,rev:'2.2.5',capture,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,ctl:auditLogParts=+E,block,msg:'SQL Injection Attack',id:'959072',tag:'WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-19',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A1',tag:'OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1',tag:'PCI/6.5.2',logdata:'%{TX.0}',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}"
```

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
http://server.invalid/test.php?pretty_arg=test123&ugly_arg=345test

ARGS_NAMES = "pretty_arg","ugly_arg"
ARGS = "pretty_arg:test123","ugly_arg:345test"
```

See here:

- [Reference-Manual Variables](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#variables)
- [Reference-Manual args](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#args)

If you want to remove the argument from a specific call, you could use

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@streq /path/to/file.php" "phase:1,id:2001,t:none,nolog,pass,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=959072;ARGS:ugly_arg"
```

Comment: I see.. Can you give an example with reference to the sec rule i mentioned above? My understanding give me something like if a name + value pair contains something that matches the regex then it would give a positive. From what you say, i assume that here ARGS would be "name of the html textarea:value of the textarea". 

So suppose instead of removing the rule altogether if i were to put a exception should i do a !ARGS:fieldname or !ARGS_NAMES:fieldname.

the 2nd one appears to be somewhat marginally logical to me . I am a novice in this mod_sec thing!

Comment: Updated it... hope that helps ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have a little confusion here though. When you gave and example for ARGS you gave it as ARGS = "ugly_arg:345test" . 

But when creating a custom exception, its ^ARGS:ugly_arg ... Ummm, logically shouldnt it be "ugly_arg:345test" ? Well i have tried and it doesnt work all right... What you said works.. I am just wondering why this convention..

Comment: Sorry if I confused you...maybe you should see ARGS as an array with Key<->Value, the key is the argument-name, the value is the value of the argument. Your problem is in the value of an argument, so you say so remove the argument with the name "ugly_arg" from the target-list.

Comment: Thnaks! I get the drift now.